# Array values change inside useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a File Upload component, whenever a file is added, we try uploading it if there aren't any errors. If any error (issue with types/sizes/network etc) is encountered, we set the error key in the file object with the type of error received.

The issue in my case is that whenever the Files array is updated, I've a useEffect hook in place to update a error state, to render the error component.

Here is the `useEffect` hook:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (files.length === 0) {
        setError?.(false);
    }

    console.log("FilesArray before filter =>", files);

    const errorFiles = files.filter((file, index) => {
        console.log("FilesArray =>", file, `File at index = ${index}`, file, "fileError =>", file.error);
        return file.error;
    });

    console.log("FilesArray after filter =>", files, "ErrorFiles Array =>", errorFiles);

    setError?.(errorFiles.length !== 0, errorFiles);
}, [files]);
```

I've tried adding console logs inside filter function as well, and the issue is files array logged just before & after filter has "technicalError" in error key whereas the files array logged inside filter method doesn't have one.

Here's a snapshot from the console.

[image]

Comment: this looks like an example of how to not use `useEffects`. What is stopping you from just setting the error when you set files?

Comment: What is `setError`? Is it really a nullable function with dynamic parameters?

Comment: Can you create a sandbox for this?

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess, I'd say you have some code elsewhere that is mutating this `files` array reference, whatever it is. Can you [edit] to post a complete [mcve] of all the relevant code you are working with?

Comment: Sorry, but I won't be able to share any more code. We found the issue actually, as @DrewReese pointed out "you have some code elsewhere that is mutating this files array". We were mutating the state wrongly. 

Something of this sort:

`setFiles(_files => {
    let index = 0;
    const file = _files[index];
    file.error = "randomError";
    _files[index] = file;
    return _files;
})`

I came across https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#updating-arrays-without-mutation 

Making a new array and using it across fixed my issue `const tempArr = [..._files];`

Answer (score -1):

Ensure you operate on a stable copy of the files array inside the useEffect hook by creating a shallow copy (filesCopy). This prevents unexpected behavior caused by closures and ensures accurate filtering of files with errors.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (files.length === 0) {
        setError?.(false);
    }

    const filesCopy = [...files]; // Create a shallow copy of the files array

    const errorFiles = filesCopy.filter((file, index) => file.error);

    setError?.(errorFiles.length !== 0, errorFiles);
}, [files]);
```

Comment: What kind of unexpected behavior do you expect here? `Array#filter()` creates a new array without changing the old one, so in a sense it's already a shallow, *not copy but subset*. And what would be "**not** accurate filtering" of an array and how does this shallow copy help with that?